# How to say something is 'easy to learn'?

Tags: translation

Is there a grammar pattern to attach a adjective to a noun in this way?

Answer (score 6):

There are some cases where it is possible.

For example, using やすい and づらい after the stem of a verb.

> 見づらい -> hard to see
>   読みやすい -> easy to read
>   覚えやすい -> easy to learn/remember
>   書きづらい -> hard to write

にくい can be used in the same way as づらい and has mostly the same meaning but is slightly more objective. (Thanks to @Blavius for reminding me)

Comment: And don't forget にくい

Comment: Related:  [The differences between ～がたい、〜にくい、〜づらい](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3279/78)

Answer (score 2):

As explained by [stack reader](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42820/18582), the typical grammar used is `stem + やすい`.

However, the verb can also be nominalized with `plain form + こと` or `plain form + の`, and an adjective meaning "easy" can be added. I picked 「簡単{かんたん}」, but you could go with 「容易{ようい}」, 「易{やさ}しい」...

This gives you the three following possible ways of saying "easy to learn" (in the plain form), using 「習{なら}う」 as "learn", which is the most generic:

- 習{なら}いやすい
- 習{なら}うことが簡単{かんたん}だ
- 習{なら}うのが簡単{かんたん}だ

About how to use them, remember that a sentence in the plain from can be used as a qualifier:

> 習{なら}いやすくても、時間{じかん}がかかるよ。
>
> Even though it's easy to learn, it takes some time.

「習{なら}いやすい」 is used as an adjective (actually, it **is** an adjective, just as "easy to learn").

> 習{なら}うことが簡単{かんたん}な言語{げんご}と言{い}うものはない。
>
> There is no such thing as a language easy to learn.

「習{なら}うことが簡単{かんたん}」 is used as a qualifying group, ending with a な-adjective.

---

I recommend you the reading of [this excellent post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1396/18582) about the differences between の and こと nominalization.

Comment: 「習うことが簡単な言語ということがない。」はおかしいです。「There is no such thing as~~」は「～～などというものはない」、「～～なんていうものはない」のように言います

Comment: @Schokolade 済みません、「こと」と「もの」は結構紛らわしいです。「～というものはない」は、いいでしょうか。

Comment: はい、いいと思います。------

Comment: @Schokolade ありがとうございました。済みません、関係しなくて、失礼ですが、日本人かドイツ人ですか。

Comment: 日本人です＾＾　すみません、名前だけドイツ語でややこしいですが。しょっちゅう名前を変えてしまって。そのうちまた chocolate に戻します

Answer (score 1):

The following could be the typical situation.

「僕は、スキーをしたことがないよ」I've never enjoyed skiing.

「やってごらんよ。簡単だよ」Try it, it's easy to learn.

Thus we Japanese often ommit the noun phrase.
The complete sentense should be 「習うのは簡単だよ.」

Just the word "hard" has the way to connect it with a noun phrase.

> "hard to accept" = 「受け入れるのは難しい」 = 「受け入れ難い{がたい}」
>   "hard to access" = 「近づくのは難しい」 = 「近づき難い」

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you take the verb stem from ます-form and modify it with:

**やすい** - for things that are easy to do

> 読｛よ｝みやすい - easy to read
>
> 食｛た｝べやすい - easy to eat
>
> 習｛なら｝いやすい - easy to learn

**にくい** - for things that are difficult

> 開｛あ｝けにくい - difficult/hard to open
>
> 飲｛の｝みにくい - difficult/hard to drink/swallow
>
> 覚｛おぼ｝えにくい - difficult/hard to memorize/remember

Both やすい and にくい conjugate as  い-adjectives, and you can use them in the same way as い-adjectives.

たとえば、

> 読｛よ｝みにくい本｛ほん｝- book that's hard to read

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score -1):

It's sometimes possible.
In order to say `easy to ...`, we use **`...やすい`**. (Learn is 学ぶ in Japanese) So I would say:

> - (何か)は/が **学びやすい**。
>
>   - (Something) is easy to learn.