# What is the difference between 言いだし and 言いだす?

Tags: word-choice, words, etymology, conjugations

I found a sentence earlier containing the word 言いだしづら but I parsed it to 2 words and I found I did not know 言いだし so I looked it up and found 言いだす (which I know the meaning of), but I also found another site saying 言いだし is the same thing basically, but I don't know why there is a し. Is this a different word or a conjugation I forgot?

Comment: The difference is the same as that between 出し and 出す. 出す -> 出しづらい, 言い出す -> 言い出しづらい.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42820/9831

Answer (score 3):

言いだし is the continuative form (連用形) of 言いだす ([言]{い}い[出]{だ}す).

> Examples:
>   dictionary form - continuative form
>   [言]{い}う - 言**い**
>   [出]{だ}す - 出**し**
>   言いだす - 言いだ**し**
>   する - **し**
>   わかる - わか**り**

「[Continuative form of a verb] + づらい」 means "hard/difficult to [Verb]".
<sub>づらい comes from an i-adjective **つ**らい ([辛]{つら}い), "painful, difficult, tough, hard". The つ gets voiced into づ due to [[連濁]{れんだく}](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/9831).</sub>

> Examples:
>   言う + つらい → 言**い**づらい "hard to say"
>   言いだす + つらい → 言いだ**し**づらい "hard to start talking / hard to speak out"
>   わかる + つらい → わか**り**づらい "hard to understand"
>   外出する + つらい → 外出**し**づらい "hard to go out"

Comment: thank you! just a question, what do you mean by continuative form when i search for it all i come up with is the つて conjugation

Comment: @user38996 You could try "the *i* form" or "ren'yōkei", as in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#i_form), or "pre *masu* form", or "verb stem".