# Can you use 観にくい( 観る+にくい) to say that something is hard to watch in the sense of that the topic/images might be hard to stomach?

Tags: grammar, usage

Example would: この第二次世界大戦についてドキュメンタリーはちょっと観にくいけど、本当に面白いと思う。work to say: This documentary about WW2 is a bit hard to watch (hard to stomach) but it is very interesting.

Comment: I think you'd use 観づらい instead for such a subjective meaning.  観にくい sounds to me like there's something wrong with the production/media of the documentary, or that you have trouble accessing it.  But I could see wrong about that.  See [The differences between ～がたい、〜にくい、〜づらい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3279/78) for more info.

Comment: If you mean 'very unpleasant' by 'hard to watch', neither 観にくい nor 見づらい works.

Comment: 第二次世界大戦について**の**ドキュメンタリー

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean it is the content that makes you feel "hard to watch (keep watching)", then you are already receiving some information from that. In this case, 観にくい is not applicable. It would mean that you have difficulty bringing yourself to the point ready to watch, because e.g. hard to obtain, tape is damaged, resolution is too low etc. I think you need to be a bit more specific which aspects in the content make you uncomfortable.

> 観るのがつらい／きつい *painful to watch* (not 観づらい)
> 観て楽しいものではない *not very pleasant to watch*
> わかりにくい *hard to understand*

Or as a workaround, 観やすくない "not easy to watch" could be understood vaguely that there is something not easygoing inside.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t. 観づらい doesn’t work, either. You can say 観るのがつらい, instead.

Or you should explicitly say how you feel when you watch it, like 観ると悲しくなる.